# How to access contents of an EBS volume attached to an ec2 instance from a python application deployed in an ECS using Fargate

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Please forgive me, I am a beginner in AWS and have very limited knowledge, but have got a scenario to work with in my hands.

I have a python application that I have deployed in Amazon ECS using Fargate(using CloudFormation template). I also have loads of ec2 instances running separately where I have attached EBS volumes to some of them. How can I access a particular EBS volume contents attached to an ec2 from my deployed python code in ECS?

Note: I do not want to make use of S3 here and I want to directly connect to an EBS volume from my python application.

Any help will greatly be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is not a good architectural design. Sharing drives between computers is typically painful. Let's start simple... if you wanted to share EBS access between two EC2 instances, how would you do it? Then, see whether you can use the same method to share with the Fargate container.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein to be fair, EBS can be attached to multiple EC2 instances in the same AZ now. But that doesn't help with Fargate.

Comment: You should look into using EFS instead of EBS for this.

Comment: @MarkB Oh yeah, I keep forgetting that new multi-attach feature! Thanks! I agree, EFS would be better in this situation -- it is a network filesystem that can be attached to multiple instances and "accessed in common" rather than needing anything copied between computers.